# How to call "NuGet.exe restore" from Jenkins Pipeline on Wndows?

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

#### What I want

calling the "NuGet.exe restore" from a batch step.

#### What I did before Jenkins 2.0

I added a Batch step and typed:

```
%WORKSPACE%/.nuget/NuGet.exe restore pathToSln
```

#### What I do in Jenkins 2

```
node('hudsoncsharp02') {
    stage('NuGet'){
        dir ('.nuget'){
            bat 'NuGet.exe restore'
        }
    }
}
```

#### Results in

```
[Pipeline] node
Running on hudsoncsharp02 in C:\xxxx\pipeline-git
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (NuGet Restore)
[Pipeline] dir
Running in C:\xxxx\pipeline-git\.nuget
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] bat
[.nuget] Running batch script

C:\xxxx\pipeline-git\.nuget>C:\xxxx\pipeline-git\.nuget\NuGet.exe restore 
Der Befehl "C:\xxxx\pipeline-git\.nuget\NuGet.exe" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.
```

In English - the file NuGet.exe could not be found in the .nuget folder.

But it is clearly there when browsing the workspace.

#### Questions

- Do the bat steps get executed directly in the workspace or somewhere else, where relative paths wont work?

  - If they do get executed somewhere else. How do I call my NuGet.exe from there?

Answer (score 0):

Missed the checkout step.
Thought Jenkins would do this by its own.